# Why is this DataTemplate inside a ListView not updating its binding automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
namespace WpfBindingProblem
{
    public class Top
    {
        public IList<Mid> MidList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Mid>();
    }

    public class Mid
    {
        public IList<Bot> BotList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Bot>();
    }

    public class Bot
    {
    }
}
```

And I have this XAML window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBindingProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfBindingProblem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="217.267" Width="333.686">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Top/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TriggersToString x:Key="TriggersToString"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding MidList}" x:Name="ThatList">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Mid}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BotList, Converter={StaticResource TriggersToString}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Add mid" Click="AddMid"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Add bot to selected mid" Click="AddBot" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

With these handlers:

```
namespace WpfBindingProblem
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddMid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(DataContext is Top p)
            {
                p.MidList.Add(new Mid());
            }
        }

        private void AddBot(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(ThatList.SelectedItem is Mid c)
            {
                c.BotList.Add(new Bot());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this converter (as a stand-in for any arbitrary converter):

```
namespace WpfBindingProblem
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(IList<Bot>), typeof(string))]
    public class TriggersToString : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value is IList<Bot> list)
            {
                return list.Count.ToString();
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

In the window that appears when we run this example, I can right click and choose "Add mid" so an instance of `Mid` is added to the `Top` data context, and the list view is updated accordingly, showing the number 0 (as per the conversion logic)

However, when I click "Add bot to selected mid", an instance of `Bot` is added to the selected `Mid` (I can verify this using breakpoints), but the list view is not updated accordingly (I expected 0 to be changed to 1, but the converter is not called again for that particular instance of `Mid`).

Why does this change not trigger an update of the GUI?

I know I can work around this with some hacks (like setting the data context to `null` and back, or possibly by invoking explicit updates using dependency properties), but there are two reasons why I'd like to avoid that:

- My actual code is more complex than this MCVE and it would look very ugly.
- I've already sprinkled all my (actual) classes with all the required the `ObservableCollection`s and the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces, precisely so that I wouldn't need to perform manual updates — so I feel like automatic updates should happen in this case, unless I've missed something.

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding BotList.Count}"/>` should update the UI. That is because the BotList property itself doesn't change when you add an element. However, its Count property does.

Comment: @Clemens I see. However, this is specific to this particular converter whose logic can be replicated in XAML. Is there a more general way so that I can use an arbitrary converter?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. `{Binding BotList}` will simply not get triggered by adding or removing elements to/from BotList.

Comment: @Clemens I'm trying to understand why — is it because it's bound to `Text` instead of an `ItemsSource` property?

Comment: Yes. When you bind the ItemsSource property, the ItemsControl checks if the source collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged. If so, it attaches a CollectionChanged event handler. So in contrast to INotifyPropertyChanged, where the Binding attaches a PropertyChanged handler, it's the control that attaches the `...Changed` handler.

Comment: You can use multi binding (one binding binds to your collection and another binds to collection Count), as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this change not trigger an update of the GUI?

Because the source property of the binding (`BotList`) is not updated. The converter is invoked only when the data bound property is updated.

You could use a `MultiBinding` as suggested by @Sinatr or you could

- bind directly to the `Count` property of the collection:

  ```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding BotList.Count}" />
  ```
- implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the `Mid` class and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `BotList` property whenever an item is added to it. Handle `CollectionChanged`.

You might also move your convert logic to the view model, bind to a property of this one and also raise the `PropertyChanged` for it whenever you want the binding to be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multi binding:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TriggersToString}">
            <Binding Path="BotList" />
            <Binding Path="BotList.Count" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

and multi value converter:

```
public class TriggersToString : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        (values[0] as IList<Bot>)?.Count.ToString(); // first binding

    ...
}
```

This way the converter is called whenever either of bindings is updated.